# 2 divs, 100% minus 250px width possible?

Tags: css

I have 2 divs that have full height,
one on the left and one on the right,
the one on the right has to be 250px width,
the one on the left must fill the remaining area (fluid).

Can it be done?
If only width: 100% - 250px; worked huh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just float the 250px one to the right and give the one that expands a right margin of 250px.

```
<div class="right">
    Some right content
</div>
<div class="main">
    Some main content
</div>
```

```css
.right {
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
}
.main {
    margin-right: 250px;
}​
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jAf9u/)

That won't expand their heights to be the same if one is larger than the other, but I think you have that covered already, no?